# What Tantras say on Kevala Kumbhaka?

Tags: tantra, hatha-yoga

In the advanced Yoga, there is stage Kevala Kumbhaka which means effortless breathlessness. This means you surpass inhalation retention and exhalation process and you attain Kevala Kumbhaka.

But my question here is what Tantras say on Kevala Kumbaka? In Kevala Kumbhaka what exactly happens and does sadhak realize Lord Shiva in this state?

Request the answer exclusively from Tantras.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the 9th Chapter of Kularnava Tantram, Mother Goddess wants to know from Lord Shiva the signs of Yoga and Yogi (Yoga/Yogi Lakshanam).

In this context, Lord Shiva speaks about the various signs of Yogi and Yoga and the full chapter consists of 134 such verses.

Among those, few verses are talking about the state what you refer to as **Kevala Kumbhaka** --- where the breathing has actually stopped. Although the term "Kevala Kumbhaka" isn't mentioned.

First such hint is given in the 8th verse itself:

> pranashta-vAyu-sanchArah pAshAna iva nishchalah |
>  parajivasya
> marmagyo yogi yogavid-uchyate ||
>
> In whom the flow of (prAna etc.) VAyus have stopped; who is immobile
> like a rock, who has the knowledge of the Parajiva (or Param Purush),
> such a Yogi is known as an adept of Yoga (Yogavid).8

The very next verse then describes the state of SamAdhi.

And then in verses 11 and 12, Lord Shiva says:

> swapna-jAgrata-avasthAyam suptavat yoha-avatishtathe |
> nishwAsocchAs-hinashcha nishchitam mukta eva sah ||
>
> Who resides in the Dream and Wake up states as Supta (asleep), such a
> Yogi, who is devoid of inhalation and exhalation, is certainly
> liberated. 11
>
> Nishpanda-karana-grAmah swAtma-linamanoha-nilah |
>  ya Aste
> mritavat-sAkshAt jivanmuktah sa uchyate ||
>
> One, whose sense organs have stopped pulsating; mind and vital airs
> (VAyus like prAna, apAna etc.) have all turned inwardly; and who
> resides just like a dead person, is known to be a Jivanmukta (one who
> is liberated while Living) 12.

So, what you are referring to as Kevala Kumbhaka, is seemingly the highest state for the Yogi to achieve. It's a state in Samadhi where all functioning of breathing has actually stopped and the Yogi appears to be as dead. Only Jivanmukta Yogis can achieve this state it seems.

Comment: So Kevala Kumbhaka is the highest state where yogi finds union with Shiva. We need blessings of him to merge back to him in that stage.

Comment: Yes that's right @AgamasTantras

Answer (score 1):

Kumbhaka is basically a breathing-cum-meditation practice which is also mentioned in Tantra. It is among three types of internal prāṇāyāma:

1. Puraka - means inhaling the breath
2. Rechaka - means exhaling breath
3. **Kumbhaka - means retaining breath.**

As per svachhanda Tantra,

> अपसव्येन रेच्येत सव्येनैव तु पूरयेत् ।
> नाडीनां शोधनं ह्येतन्मोक्षमार्गपथस्य च ॥ 
> रेचनात्पूरणाद्रोधात्प्राणायामास्त्रिधा स्मृताः ।
>
> सामान्या बहिरेते तु पुनश्चाभ्यन्तरे त्रयः ॥ 
> आभ्यन्तरेण रेच्येत पूर्येताभ्यन्तरेण तु ।
>
>  निःस्पन्दं **कुम्भकं** कृत्वा कार्याश्चाभ्यन्तरास्त्रयः ॥
>
> > "One should breathe in through the left (nose) and breathe out through the right. This brings about cleansing of the nädis (channels) and of the middle nadi which is the path to liberation. By breathing out, by breathing in, and by restraining or stopping the breath, there are said to be three types of pranayama. They are all common and external. There are also three types of internal prāṇāyāma. By the internal one has to perform the recaka, by the internal one has to perform the puraka and by the internal one has to perform tremorless **kumbhaka**. Thus the three internal prānāyāmas should be performed."

This gets a better explanation in Vijnanabhairava Tantra, **verse 90, Dharana 67**:

> अबिन्दुमविसर्गं च अकारं जपतो महान् । 
> उदेति देवि सहसा ज्ञानौघः परमेश्वरः ॥ १० ॥
>
> > If one recites the letter "a" without bindu or visarga then, O goddess, Paramešvara-a magnificent torrent of wisdom appears suddenly.
> >
> > > Bindu in this context indicates the anusvära or dot on a letter. which is the symbol of nasal pronunciation. Visarga indicates two dots placed one upon the other immediately after a letter which symbolize the articulation of a letter with sound. Thus (a) with bindu would be (am), and a (a) with visarga would be a: (ah).
> > >
> > > **In sounding 'a' with anusvära i. e. as am there will be inhalation (püraka) and in sounding 'a' with visarga i. e. as ah there will be exhalation (recaka). The above dharana says that the letter wa' should be recited without a bindu i. e. without an amusvära, and also without a visarga (without the *h* sound) i. e. neither with inhalation nor with exhalation( neither with püraka nor with recaka). This implies that the letter "a" should be recited in a *kumbhaka* state i.e. in a state of the retention of the breath as "a".**

Now we will cover the next question, i.e.:
**- Does sadhak realize Lord Shiva in this state?**

> First of all, **why in Kumbhaka state, sound "a" should be contemplated on/recitation?** Because letter "a" is the initial letter of the alphabet; it is the source and origin of all other letters; it is neither generated out of any other letter, nor is it dissolved in any other letter. Secondly it symbolizes the absolute, the state which is beyond description, the state in which Shiva and Shakti are in indistinguishable unity. The recitation of "a", therefore, betokens the longing of the soul for **Shiva-Shakti-Shamarasya(the state of the harmonious fusion of Shiva Shakti)** a nostalgia for its ultimate source.

> Thirdly "a" represents aham, the perfect I-consciousness of the Absolute. **Therefore, the contemplation of "a" establishes one in the absolute I-consciousness of Shiva.**

**- Bonus points which may be useful to understand and relate:**

While making commentary on this verse Svami Lakshmanjoo maharaj interprets *kumbhakasthasya* occurring in the commentary in a different way. According to him :

> kumbhakasthasya here means cakitmudraayaam sthitasya i.e. in the posture of cakitmudraa. In this posture, the mouth is wide open and tongue is held back. In this posture "a" can neither be recited with anusvaara nor with visarga. The aspirant will automatically compelled to contemplate over "a" only mentally.

This gives hint of one of the well known mudra Khechari mudra. The same mudra is mentioned in verse 77, dharana 54:

> करङ किण्या क्रोधनया भैरव्या लेलिहानया । 
> **खैचर्या** दृष्टिकाले च परावाप्तिः प्रकाशते ॥ ७७ ॥
>
> > At the moment of the (intuitive) perception (of the universe), there is manifested the supreme attainment through the Karang kini, Krodhanaa, Bhairavi, Lelihāna and **Khecari** mudrās.
> >
> > > There are four kinds of Khecari mudraa.... *The third kind of khecari is as described ib Viveka-maartanda. The tongue should be turned back inside the cranium. The gaze should be directed towards the centre in between the eye-brows.*

So third kind of khecari is same as what Swami ji's commentary is on kumbhaka.